# Is it possible to group (aggregate) objects with dates into incremental intervals in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I am currently trying to create an aggregation pipeline in MongoDB to group the items into incremental time intervals, but I only succeeded in grouping them in disjoint time intervals so far.

Sample data:

```
{
  "eventID": "abc",
  "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:05:11.790Z"),
  ...........
},
{
  "eventID": "xyz",
  "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:12:11.790Z"),
  ...........
},
{
  "eventID": "klm",
  "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:28:11.790Z"),
  ...........
}
```

Current solution:

```
$group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": { $year: "$date" },
                "dayOfYear": { $dayOfYear: "$date" },
                "hour": { $hour: "$date" },
                "interval": {
                    "$subtract": [ 
                        { "$minute": "$date" },
                        { "$mod": [{ "$minute": "$date"}, 10 ] }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "grouped_data": { "$push": { "eventID": "$eventID", "date": "$date" },
            "count": { $sum: 1 } }
        }
```

Which returns the data grouped in 10 minutes intervals but those are disjoint intervals (time windows of 10minutes that do not intersect).
Eg:

```
{
   "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "dayOfYear": "314",
      "hour": 12,
      "interval": 0, // = interval beginning at minute 0 of 12th hour of the day
   },
   "grouped_data": [{ "eventID": "abc", "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:05:11.790Z" }],
   "count": 1
},
{
   "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "dayOfYear": "314",
      "hour": 12,
      "interval": 10, // = beginning at minute 10
   },
   "grouped_data": [{ "eventID": "xyz", "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:12:11.790Z") }],
   "count": 1
},
{
   "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "dayOfYear": "314",
      "hour": 12,
      "interval": 20, // = beginning at minute 20
   },
   "grouped_data": [{ "eventID": "klm", "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:28:11.790Z") }],
   "count": 1
}
```

What I am actually looking for is grouping them in 10 minutes(or whatever is needed) *incremental* intervals. Eg: 0-9, 1-10, 2-11, etc. instead of 0-9, 10-19, 20-29 etc.

Edit:
**The end goal here is** to check if a count threshold is surpassed on a interval length defined by the user.
If user asks **"Are there more than 2 events on a 10minute time window?"**, based on the sample data above and my current solution, the condition is not met. (1 event in 0-9 interval, and 1 event in 10-19). With incremental intervals I should be able to find that there are indeed 2 events in 10 minutes, but in the time interval 5-14. Eg:

```
{
   "_id": {
      *whatever logic for grouping in 10minutes window*
   },
   "grouped_data": [
      { "eventID": "abc", "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:05:11.790Z") },
      { "eventID": "xyz", "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:12:11.790Z") }],
   "count": 2
},
{
   "_id": {
      *whatever logic for grouping in 10minutes window*
   },
   "grouped_data": [
      { "eventID": "klm", "date": ISODate("2020-11-05T12:28:11.790Z") }]
   "count": 1
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question, maybe it will help other people on the internet. The solution I came up with is based on the answer of @Wernfried (thanks!).

```
db.getCollection("events_en").aggregate([
    {
        $match: { eventID: "XYZ" }
    },
    {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         events: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
         limit: { $push: { $toDate: { $add: [{ $toLong: "$date" }, 1000 * 60 * 10] } } }
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$limit" },
    {
      $project: {
         events: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$events", 
               cond: {
                  $and: [
                     { $lt: ["$$this.date", "$limit"] },
                     { $gte: ["$$this.date", { $subtract: ["$limit", 1000 * 60 * 10] }] },
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         limit: 1,
      }
   },
   {
       $addFields: {
         count: {
            $size: "$events" 
         }
      }
   }
])
```

This will create a limit for each event, based on its date + 10 minutes (or whatever). And afterwards it filters the events (which are now duplicated for each of the limit using $unwind: "$limit"), based on that limit. The result is something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "limit" : ISODate("2020-11-05T12:28:27.000+0000"), 
    "events" : [
        {
            "_id" : 13, 
            "eventID" : "XYZ", 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-05T12:18:27.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 63, 
            "eventID" : "XYZ", 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-05T12:19:55.000+0000")
        }, 
        ............................
        {
            "_id" : 90, 
            "eventID" : "XYZ", 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-05T12:27:57.000+0000")
        }
    ], 
    "count" : 5
}
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "limit" : ISODate("2020-11-05T12:29:55.000+0000"), 
    "events" : [
        {
            "_id" : 63, 
            "eventID" : "XYZ", 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-05T12:19:55.000+0000")
        },
        {
            "_id" : 90, 
            "eventID" : "XYZ", 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-05T12:27:57.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 97, 
            "eventID" : "XYZ", 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-05T12:29:36.000+0000")
        }
    ], 
    "count" : 3
}
```

As you can see, looking at the limit of each group and at the dates of the events in each group, these intervals are now incremental, not disjoint. (event X is found in multiple groups, as long as it doesnt exceeds the time interval of 10minutes)

Answer (score 1):

For me it is not clear which output you like to get, but this aggregation pipeline makes the sliding-window group:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
         min_date: { $min: "$date" },
         max_date: { $max: "$date" }
      }
   },
   {
      $addFields: {
         interval: {
            $range: [
               { $toInt: { $divide: [{ $toLong: "$min_date" }, 1000] } },
               { $toInt: { $divide: [{ $toLong: "$max_date" }, 1000] } },
               10 * 60]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         interval: {
            $map: {
               input: "$interval",
               in: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$$this", 1000] } }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$interval" },
   {
      $project: {
         grouped_data: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$data", 
               cond: {
                  $and: [
                     { $gte: ["$$this.date", "$interval"] },
                     { $lt: ["$$this.date", { $add: ["$interval", 1000 * 60 * 10] }] },
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         interval: 1
      }
   }
])
```

Boundaries are given by input data, however can also use fixes dates:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $addFields: {
         interval: {
            $range: [
               { $toInt: { $divide: [{ $toLong: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z") }, 1000] } },
               { $toInt: { $divide: [{ $toLong: ISODate("2020-12-31T23:59:59Z") }, 1000] } },
               10 * 60]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         interval: {
            $map: {
               input: "$interval",
               in: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$$this", 1000] } }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$interval" },
   {
      $project: {
         grouped_data: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$data", 
               cond: {
                  $and: [
                     { $gte: ["$$this.date", "$interval"] },
                     { $lt: ["$$this.date", { $add: ["$interval", 1000 * 60 * 10] }] },
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         interval: 1
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not able to work with "$set" stage because I am on MongoDB 4.0 and $set requires v4.2. I will try to understand your "sliding window" logic  because it sounds like it is what I need.

Comment: Use synonym `$addFields` instead of `$set`

Comment: @Wernfriue Indeed, I used $addFields, thanks! About your solution, isnt it also making disjoint intervals? I am a bit confused now that I spent a bit with it. I updated the question if your are willing to have a second look, with improved examples.

Comment: Sorry for misspelling your name previously. As an update, indeed your solutions looks like still returns disjoint intervals, like mine. I tried it and I discovered that I could still find a better interval that contained more events in it, than those returned by this pipeline. The issue seems to be the fact that intervals are constructed based on the first event, while I would need that for each event to take the next 10 minutes (or whatever input) of events and count them.